# Экспорт таблицы БД (OrmLite) в Excel (*.xls) на Android

Tags: java, android, excel, sqlite, sql

**Дано:**

Есть БД в приложении под андроид. Для работы с ней пользуется [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/).

**Задача:**

Надо её, базы, содержимое посмотреть в виде таблиц Excel для целей дебага.

**Что сделано:**

Гугл не сильно в этом помогает. Всё, что он мне выдал, - это [ссылка](http://sunil-android.blogspot.ru/2013/09/export-and-import-data-db-table-to-csv.html), в коей описано, как таблицу БД преобразовать в *.CSV файл и отправить его по почте. Немного попрыгав с бубном, я добился отправки всех моих таблиц в виде файлов на почту и ручного их преобразования в* .xls таблицы.

**Вопрос:**

Есть ли способ ещё больше оптимизировать/ автоматизировать процесс? В идеале хотелось бы прямо в приложении преобразовывать таблицы БД в таблицы Excel. Ну или *.csv файлы в таблицы Excel. В данный же момент приходится руками открывать* .csv файлы и преобразовывать их в *.xls путём тыкания в кнопку "далее" на компе в Excel.

**UPD_0:**

По [ссылке](http://www.aspose.com/blogs/aspose-products/aspose-cells-product-family/archive/2013/08/06/introducing-aspose.cells-for-android.html) [[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf), вроде как то, что нужно, но очень большая либа. Сразу получил over65K методов и +6 Мб в вес проекта. Если не найдётся чего "полегче" буду юзать отдельным приложением и напишу тут в ответе, кратко, как им пользоваться.

Comment: Например: http://www.aspose.com/blogs/aspose-products/aspose-cells-product-family/archive/2013/08/06/introducing-aspose.cells-for-android.html

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо, вроде то, что нужно, но... Но я начал тестить и получил сначала нехватку памяти у Эклипса, потом превышение 65К методов( Судя по тому, что нагуглил, гугловая либа для решения сего трабла сработает только в AndroidStudio. В общем нема ли либы для экспорта в xls поменьше размером? =)
Не оперативу же мне докупать, да на "студию" перелезать)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нехватка эклипса лечится изменением настроек запуска в конфиге. А 65к методов лечится прогуардом )

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо, нехватку памяти уже вылечил, методами ща займусь. Нагуглил, что можно как то либу с гугло-сервисами порезать руками... О адЪ! Я всего-то хотел 3-и файла получить(((

Comment: @ЮрийСПб мы не ищем лёгких путей =D

Comment: @Suvitruf, да уж) Раз уж пошла такая пьянка, буду в виде отдельного приложения делать, в него слать инструкции и получать обратно ссылки на файлы... Не должно же быть проблем при доступе одного моего приложения к БД другого, да? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Должно. Напрямую не получится  получить доступ к базе. Только если контент провайдер замутить((:

Comment: @Suvitruf, эх... Ладно, всё одно надо и его изучить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как упомянуто в вопросе, по [ссылке](http://www.aspose.com/blogs/aspose-products/aspose-cells-product-family/archive/2013/08/06/introducing-aspose.cells-for-android.html) [[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf) есть либа, позволяющая работать с XLS файлами. Вот пример:

```
        File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
        "");

        String path = exportDir.getCanonicalPath();

        //Instantiate a Workbook object.
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        //Get the first worksheet's cells in the book.
        Cells cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells();

        //insert column names
        int columnQuont=3;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnQuont; i++)
        {
            cells.get(0, i).setValue("название_колонки");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < columnQuont; i++)
        {
            String data = "что-нибудь";
            cells.get(1, i).setValue(data);
        }

        //Save the Excel file.
        workbook.save(path + "/ArticleXLS.xls");
```

Соответственно, нужно просто собрать из БД данные и записать их в файл.

Правда, либа эта платная. Цена - $999 (sic!) или **максимальное кол-во разрешённых методов в андроид приложении** в рублях по нынешнему курсу.
Скачать её по ссылке можно, но не очень понятно, чем чревато её пользование не для целей тестирования, за исключением добавления страницы в итоговом файле с надписью:

> Evaluation Only. Created with Aspose.Cells for Android.Copyright 2003 - 2015 Aspose Pty Ltd.

P.S. Итого, проблема решаема, если рассматривать её в более широком смысле и гуглить вместо означенного в заголовке вопроса просто

> android xls library

Что выдаёт [опэнсорс либу](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) и [пример её пользования](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html).

Comment: @Expert, а можно как-то свой ответ принять?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можно, но не сразу. Если его никто за тебя не примет, то спустя два дня

Comment: @Andreich, понял, спасибо) И @Expert того же)