# Приложение android для импорта введённых даных в excel

Tags: java, android, мобильные-приложения

Добрый вечер, учусь в университет и сейчас появилось задача создать мобильное приложение (в перспективе так же создать сайт с таким функционалом), суть которого в следующем:
- в интерфейсе вводятся данные полученные при измерении таксационных показателей дерева, интерфейс простейший для начала, название показателя и его значение;
- потом эти данные должны преобразоваться так, что бы на выходе получилось 2 файла, один excel с возможностью форматирования, другой word или pdf в котором все эти данные подставляются в виде форматированных таблиц (шрифты, выравнивания, отступы итд)
Как это можно реализовать? И на сколько это сложно?

Comment: Посмотрит этот ответ - там приводятся ссылки на либы и примеры для создания excel файлов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/391214/17609

Comment: это сложно. Реализовать можно при помощи библиотек, которые вы утрудитесь найти сами. Запрос в гугл: `Android excel library`

Comment: Это несложно.
Вот здесь есть инструкция: https://o7planning.org/ru/11259/read-write-excel-file-in-java-using-apache-poi