# Android отправление созданных office файлов через почтовый клиент

Tags: java, android, office

Как реализовать отправку каких-либо данных с программы прикрепленным к письму документом word или excel?

Comment: Что именно не получается? Прикрепить файл или сформировать его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делите задачу на части и также её решайте.

1. Создайте файл нужно формата и заполните его данными. В случае `*.xls` посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/391214/17609)
2. А вот так можно запустить к-л почтовый клиент, передав ему адрес, куда отправлять, тему письма, его текст и массив файлов, кои вы сделали в п.1:

   ```
   File[] myAwesomeArrayOfAwesomeFiles = ...;

   String to = "К-Л_ОФИГЕННЫЙ_АДРЕС@gmail.com";
   String subj = "я, умею, отправлять, файлы, по, почте";
   String msg = "прикинь, да?! =)))";


   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
   emailIntent.setType("text/html");
   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subj);
   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);

   ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
   for (File f : out)
   {
       uris.add(Uri.fromFile(f));
   }
   emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

   this.ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
   ```

Comment: спасибо большое буду пробовать ))))

Comment: а этот api платный?

Comment: @java, я этого так и не понял. В ответе по ссылке из п.1 есть в конце ещё ссылка на open-source либу для `*.xls`

Comment: ок посмотрю, спасибо